# Flattening a List of RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have a collection of `RDD`s:

```
val rddList = scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[RDD[Data]]()
```

that contains multiple `RDD`s of the same kind of `Data` but that are created using different sources. I need to combine these `RDD`s into a single `RDD`.

If I do an `rddList.flatten` and then take the lead element will that accomplish what I want?

Comment: You mean flatMap? Did you try it?

Comment: why are you asking us if it'll work, just try it and see if it does.

Comment: Probably not. Can you give us a couple of examples of the RDDs that you have in your list. And (minor point) is there a reason it is a mutable List?

Comment: @cricket_007 an `RDD` isn't a `Monad`, so no `flatMap`.

Comment: @Reactormonk Ah, my bad, the `rdd` part of the variable through me off

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to reduce and then union to create a single RDD from a list of RDD. Below is a simple example.

```
val r1 = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(1 to 5)
val r2 = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(5 to 10)
val r3 = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(10 to 15)

  val list = ListBuffer(r1,r2,r3)

  list.reduce(_ union _).collect().foreach(println)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Perfect. This is exactly what I was looking for. Had tried to use FlatMap as suggested above but did not work.

Comment: can you upvote and accept as an answer? If this worked.